# How to return type UILabel from a created method

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I have this

```
UILabel *selectedLabel;
    selectedLabel = nil;
    if (is_x) {
        selectedLabel = labelField_x;
    } else if (is_y) {
        selectedLabel = labelField_y;
    } else if (is_z) {
        selectedLabel = labelField_z;
    }
```

To prevent this from repeating in the code, how can I make a method that will return a type UILabel class.

I have tried this (it does't work):

in header (.h) file:

```
//new method
- (UILabel *) selected;
```

in implementation (.m) file:

```
- (UILabel *) selected {
 UILabel *selectedLabel;
    selectedLabel = nil;
    if (is_x) {
        selectedLabel = labelField_x;
    } else if (is_y) {
        selectedLabel = labelField_y;
    } else if (is_z) {
        selectedLabel = labelField_z;
    }
return selectedLabel;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
 [self selected];

}
```

How can I return selectedLabel inside the IBAction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks right, all you need to do is create a `UILabel` variable in your buttonPressed: method to store the reference to the returned label.  So change

```
[self selected];
```

to:

```
UILabel *selectedLabel = [self selected];
// Now do what you want with the selectedLabel
```